# How can I create values from a Mongodb as links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm trying to create an online discussion forum with node.js, express & mongodb. I was trying to create links that when I click them, I must be redirected to the page or each article... how can I create the links? Currently what I need to know is that, when I click an article which will be displayed from the database, I must be redirected to a page with an id of the article I have clicked. I'm using ejs templating language.

```
<ul>
<% articles.forEach((item)) => {%>



<li> <a href="/article/"+article._id> <%= item.author %> </a></li>

<% }); %>

</li>
```

Please help me guys..

Comment: What have you done already? Are you able to do db calls and retrieve documents to console log? Do you have the routes already set up?

Comment: Yes I have the routes all set up.. or is there another way I can create links all set up in the app.js file. I think that the problem is in the index.ejs file.. I don't know how I can create links with ejs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a route with parameters, for example: `app.get('/post/:postId')`, the `postId` is the parameter. Then dynamically render each post depending on the `postId` parameter.

The links should direct to `/post/somePostId`.

So, if you have setup rendering the posts in ejs, send along with the post, the post ID from the database and add that ID to an HTML tag, for example: `<a href="post/<%= postId %">Click me</a>`

Then the link should make a get request from the route you set up with paramaters, and you will render a post using the paramater.